# How do I enable OAuth with my existing MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

I have an SQL Server database with a MVC 4 internet application. How do I use OAuth with my existing database and existing user table (unfortunately called 'Customer'). I'm trying to avoid changing as much as I can. Does anyone have any helpful information?

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth works perfectly fine for me. I added `SocialUser` table to database where I store actual (server side) userID, social network userID (like facebook, twitter, google) and type of social network. Then just added reference between `Customer` table and `SocialUser` table. It's easy to check if such account exists and authorize person and add social account to user profile if this is needed.

Comment: That's good. I've created a custom implementation for the MembershipProvider to use my existing tables. Is there something else I need to provide?

Comment: check your ID's types. I store social network profile ID's as string (easier to manage them since google and fb have different formates).
Looks like this is all what you need)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/). It's shipped with VS2012, is available via NuGet, and seems to be geared more toward the ASP.NET MVC audience than simpler WCF setups.